# JavaBeans in JSP using useBean Action

Tags: jsp, javabeans

I have created the following java class.

```
  public class TestClass {  
   public TestClass () {  
   }  

   public String getName() {  
   return "Rishi";  
   }  
   }
```

And the JSP file is as follows:

```
<jsp:useBean id="test" class="TestClass" scope="session" />  

<jsp:getProperty name="test" property="name" />
```

What is wrong in the above code :

```
An error occurred at line: 3 in the jsp file: /testbeans.jsp
TestClass cannot be resolved to a type
1: 
2:        
3:       
4:        
5:        
6:
```

Answer (score 1):

`TestClass` needs to be in a package, and `<useBean>` needs to refer to the fully qualified class name. So if `TestClass` is in package `x`, then you need to use

```
<jsp:useBean id="test" class="x.TestClass" scope="session" />
```

Comment: thanks for the reply..pls confirm that is it compulsory to put the class in the package?? It's optional, if the user wants to create the package or not...

Comment: @user460920: It's not compulsory, I think, but *strongly* recommended. There's no good reason whatsoever to not put classes in a package. Don't give the user the option.